# Not able to solve application error in Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

2021-04-24T19:48:40.887714+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=monefy--webapp.herokuapp.com request_id=2ae11510-81f3-47e4-8bf6-ffdee65ef51d fwd="103.251.59.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

I have added my MONGO_URL in env variable in Heroku as well.
But not able to solve since couple of days ...

Anyone can help that how to solve this logs.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you'll have to give us a bit more to go on.  perhaps some source code - of the server route. or the client call.  also what happens when you run it locally?

Comment: hello, your question is **NOT** enough. I think you publish more details.